# Using the Go SDK, how do I set a DynamoDB table item field to a map?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to use the `UpdateItem` method to set the value of a table item field to a map. Here's what I have tried:

```
type myStruct {
  name string
}

myStructInstance := myStruct{name: "foo"}

_, err := svc.UpdateItem(&dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
  TableName: aws.String("MyTable"),
  Key: myKey,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
    ":m": {
      M: dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(*myStructInstance),
    },
  },
  UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET myField = :m"),
})
```

With this, I keep getting the error:

```
multiple-value dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap() in single-value context
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(*myStructInstance)` returns two values: `value` & `error`. You can't use it like that there. Handle the error and get the value first, and then set that value as value of `M` in your map.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I forgot that the `MarshalMap` function has two return values, so I have to do this instead:

```
av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(*myStructInstance)

_, err = svc.UpdateItem(&dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
  TableName: aws.String("MyTable"),
  Key: myKey,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
    ":m": {
      M: av,
    },
  },
  UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET myField = :m"),
})
```